# Passing a Variable Between Views

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that pulls data from a model and lists it as a set of links:

```
<p>@foreach (var genre in Model)</P

a href="@Url.Action("Index", "FullMovieList")"> class="genreItem">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => genre.GenreName)
```

My question is: how do I tell which genre has been clicked on the next page? Should i send the variable:

view -> genre controller -> fulllist controller -> view

and if so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass the genre in the querystring.

Use this overload of `Url.Action`

```
@Url.Action("Index", "FullMovieList",new { genre = genre.GenreName  })
```

This will generate the url value with querystring like `"/FullMovieList/Index?genre=someName"`

Assuming your Index action method accepts a parameter named `genre` and check the value of that and return a relevant response according to that.

```
public ActionResult Index(string genre="")
{
  if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(genre))
  {

  }
  // to do  :Return something
}
```

Comment: That is fantastic Shyju, Thank you!.

how do i use that variable on the next page?

Comment: You have it in your action method, pass that to your view.

Comment: @CodeNotFound Thanks. I missed that :)